# Not able to cross compile gRPC for QNX platform using aarch64-unknown-nto-qnx7.0.0-g++-5.4.0 compiler

Tags: c++, c++11, qnx, qnx-neutrino

I am trying to cross compile gRPC code with QNX aarch64-unknown-nto-qnx7.0.0-g++-5.4.0 compiler.
I am using a toolchain.cmake file to compile.

toolchain.cmake:

```
SET(CMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME QNX)
SET(CMAKE_SYSTEM_PROCESSOR arm)
set(CMAKE_CROSSCOMPILING 1)
set(CMAKE_SYSROOT "$ENV{TOOLCHAIN_PATH}")
set(CMAKE_C_COMPILER "$ENV{TOOLCHAIN_PATH}/usr/bin/aarch64-unknown-nto-qnx7.0.0-gcc-5.4.0")
set(CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER "$ENV{TOOLCHAIN_PATH}/usr/bin/aarch64-unknown-nto-qnx7.0.0-g++-5.4.0")
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "-Vgcc_ntoaarch64 -O2 -Wc,-Wall -DBUILDENV_qss -g -Os -Wall -march=armv8-a -mcpu=cortex-a57 -mtune=cortex-a57 \
        -fstack-protector-strong -DNDEBUG -DFMT_HEADER_ONLY -EL -DVARIANT_le -std=c++11 -stdlib=libstdc++ -lang-c++ \
        -I . \
        -I$ENV{TOOLCHAIN_PATH}/usr/include \
        -I$ENV{TOOLCHAIN_PATH}/usr/include/WF \
        -I$ENV{TOOLCHAIN_PATH}/usr/include/KHR \
        -I$ENV{INSTALL_ROOT_nto}/usr/include \
        -Wl,-L$ENV{INSTALL_ROOT_nto}/aarch64le/lib \
        -Wl,-L$ENV{INSTALL_ROOT_nto}/aarch64le/usr/lib \
        -Wl,-L$ENV{TOOLCHAIN_PATH}/aarch64le/lib \
        -Wl,-L$ENV{TOOLCHAIN_PATH}/aarch64le/usr/lib")
```

I am getting following error, even though I have used -std=c++11 (gnu++11 also tried):

```
error: #error "C++ versions less than C++11 are not supported."
error: 'constexpr' does not name a type
error: '__to_gcc_order' is not a member of 'std::__1::__gcc_atomic'
error: 'NormalizeLogSeverity' is not a member of 'absl'
```

Please help me to solve this issues.

Comment: I'd start with the #error: what #defines or similar is it testing to generate that, and why does your g++ not pass the checks? The others might be consequences of that, selecting the wrong versions of code - the __gcc_atomic structure one looks suspicious to me - but otherwise you might need to investigate and solve them yourself too.

Comment: And which version of grpc is that? I don't see that error text in 1.29.0 from GitHub.

Comment: I am using grpc version 1.27.3

Comment: Thanks. I still don't see that #error in 1.27.3. What file and line number does it come from please?

Comment: Just now I tried with verrsion 1.29.0. Still the same error.

Comment: atomic:583:15: error: 'constexpr' does not name a type
 static inline constexpr int __to_gcc_order(memory_order __order) {

usr/include/c++/v1/atomic:636:25: error: '__to_gcc_order' is not a member of 'std::__1::__gcc_atomic'
   __atomic_thread_fence(__gcc_atomic::__to_gcc_order(__order));

usr/include/c++/v1/atomic:640:25: error: '__to_gcc_order' is not a member of 'std::__1::__gcc_atomic'
   __atomic_signal_fence(__gcc_atomic::__to_gcc_order(__order));

Comment: OK, thanks - I meant the first one, the "error: #error". It's useful to know that the other ones are from your atomic header though. But I can't tell from the partial paths you've given us: is that definitely using the atomic from your QNX C++ compiler and not from /usr/include/c++ from your normal compiler?

Comment: The first one come in file /grpc/third_party/abseil-cpp/absl/base/policy_checks.h:77:2: error: #error "C++ versions less than C++11 are not supported."

Comment: Oh, fair enough, I'd forgotten about submodules for my github clone. Right, it's testing `#if __cplusplus < 201103L` which [the GCC 5.4.0 documentation](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-5.4.0/cpp/Standard-Predefined-Macros.html#Standard-Predefined-Macros) says ought to be set __cplusplus = 201103L in C++11 mode, i.e. should not pass that #if to generate the #error. I've run out of ideas, sorry.

Comment: Yes that is QXN C++ compiler path. I have trimmed the whole path, to required one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There was some licencing issue, with which I was unable to build the code.

After updating the license this issue got resolved.

Answer (score 2):

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 11)
or
-std=c++11

Comment: Thanks pi1ot, but I have tried this. But still I am facing this issue.